# How to convert internal DB models to another model for an API response?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

When I do a POST request with the following code, I get a Pydantic conversion error and I don't understand what is wrong.

```py
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    rest_id: str
    email: str
    password: str
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    nickname: str

def db_to_api_User(user : models.User) -> UserBase:
    u = UserBase()
    u.rest_id = user.rest_id
    u.email = user.email
    u.password = ""
    u.firstname = user.firstname
    u.lastname = user.lastname
    u.nickname = user.nickname
    return u

@app.post("/users/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_user(user: UserBase, db: db_dependency):
    if not user.email:
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail="email is not allowed to be empty")
    if not user.password:
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail="password is not allowed to be empty")
    user.rest_id = str(uuid4())
    new_usr = api_to_db_User(user)
    db.add(new_usr)
    db.commit()
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.rest_id == new_usr.rest_id).first()
    return db_to_api_User(user)
```

The entry gets inserted into the db and I thought you could just create a `UserBase` and return it. I don't want to expose the internal database structure since I want to abstract how it is stored. (It might be changed to different storage methods later).

The return value gives me this error:

```
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 289, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     raise exc
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     raise exc
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     raise e
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     response = await func(request)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 273, in app
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 192, in run_endpoint_function
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return await future
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     result = context.run(func, *args)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/code/main.py", line 71, in create_user
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     return db_to_api_User(user).dict()
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/code/main.py", line 51, in db_to_api_User
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     u = UserBase()
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 150, in __init__
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 6 validation errors for UserBase
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | rest_id
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | email
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | password
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | firstname
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | lastname
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  | nickname
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |   Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
draft_1-app_draft_1-1  |     For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/missing
```

Am I not allowed to create a UserBase class like I do?

Comment: See section in FastAPI docs about response models and data filtering: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#return-type-and-data-filtering. Your code `u = UserBase()` will not work because the `UserBase` class required parameters. You can try init-ing it _properly_ by passing the parameter as kwargs like `UserBase(rest_id=user.rest_id, ...)`. OR better, create a _separate_ output model as explained in the docs.

Comment: And set `model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)` on your model, and you don't have to do anything to create the response explicitly. Just return your SQLAlchemy object, and it will be automagically converted to the expected format (you might need an alias for the `password_hash` part, but I'd argue that you _should never return the hash at all_ in your response. The hash never leaves the service). So set `response_model=UserResponse` on the endpoint decorator and include the fields you want in that model - and set the configuration to load from attributes.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the suggestion. I decided to remove it entirely in the end and have custom classes for i.e. changing password, or adding a new user etc. This example served as a generic q&a solution. As you mention there is no idea to expose the password hash, with the one possible exception for debugging purposes.